# Deadlock when adding job to thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I'm having a problem with my game freezing when adding a job to the thread pool. I've been going over my code but can't find the problem.

My thread pool is mostly standard and contains a list of jobs to perform. The worker threads fetch jobs from this list and perform them. Then they signal that they finished the job (this is so I can wait for all jobs to be finished (not just started/removed from the job list) without joining the threads (I want to use them next frame too)).

```
void ThreadPool::Add(std::function<void()> job) {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mJobMutex);
        mJobs.push(job);
        ++mUnfinishedJobs;
    }

    mJobCondition.notify_one();
}

void Worker::Execute() {
    std::function<void()> job;
    while (true) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mThreadPool.mJobMutex);

            while (!mThreadPool.mStop && mThreadPool.mJobs.empty()) {
                // Wait for new job to become available.
                mThreadPool.mJobCondition.wait(lock);
            }

            if (mThreadPool.mStop)
                return;

            // Get next job.
            job = mThreadPool.mJobs.front();
            mThreadPool.mJobs.pop();
        }

        // Perform the job.
        job();

        // Signal that we finished the job.
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mThreadPool.mJobMutex);
            --mThreadPool.mUnfinishedJobs;
        }
        mThreadPool.mFinishedCondition.notify_all();
    }
}
```

Through some logging I managed to boil it down to mJobCondition.notify_one() in ThreadPool::Add. I placed some logging before and after that statement and it always hanged there. This is very odd to me. Sure, notify_one can miss the threads waiting for it, but if it does, it should just do nothing. It seems very odd to me that it would freeze on that line.

And if the problem is that I'm locking incorrectly and the thread pool and the worker thread are accessing memory at the same time shouldn't it crash and burn rather than freeze?

I'm on Windows using MinGW.

I also have a Wait and Stop method in the thread pool (which is what the mUnfinishedJobs variable is for) but I didn't include them since I know it's freezing when doing Add.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/Mx3HH0Un)'s the full threading code if you need more context.

I know I could probably use some threading library that does thread pools for me, but I want to learn how it's done.

Comment: `Worker::Execute` will never execute the job as it won't even finish the `while (true)` loop on any job enqueued.

Comment: The other thing is that you constantly recreate (?) the `std::unique_lock` while it is better handled with single object and `lock`/`unlock` it manually, rather than with `c-tor`/`d-tor`.

Comment: What do you mean the job won't be executed? Why? The execution of the job is inside the loop, not outside it, so it's fine that the while loop goes on forever (well, until mStop is true).

The brackets around the lock don't belong to the while loop. They're there to add scope so the lock is released. (Good point about not recreating the lock, though.)

Comment: The only thing that stands out to me, in this code sample, is that the condition variables get signaled after mutexes are released. This may or may not be correct. In general, I always follow the practice that condition variables get signaled before releasing the mutex that's related to the condition variable.

Comment: @Chainsawkitten I believe Sergey's confusion stems from the fact that you did not explicitly state in an extremely obvious manner how your `Worker`s are being `Execute`d, which I assume are from separate `thread`s.

Comment: @Nard Full code is in a pastebin link in the question. I create the workers in the thread pools constructor and the workers call execute in their constructor (each has a separate thread).

Comment: @Chainsawkitten Oh I didn't realize you had posted the full code. I had written my own test code using the code you provided in your post, which seems to be working fine. Perhaps you can take a look at my [test code](http://pastebin.com/vfHVpATz) while I take a look at yours.

Comment: You may consider using `pop_front` instead of `pop` if you get your job with `front`. Edit: my bad, `pop` will call `pop_front`.

Comment: @knivil I'm using `queue`, not `deque` (although it uses it internally) `queue` only has `pop` (which is front), not `pop_front`.

Comment: @Nard Shouldn't your code never finish, since the worker threads will never finish (you never set `mStop` so they'll keep looping forever and never be able to join)?

Comment: I would try another compiler, e.g. vs2015.

Comment: @Chainsawkitten I figured that was not of importance to the question but since you requested, [here](http://pastebin.com/hJAiw1UE). I've also added a pause in between the adding of jobs to force the behavior of the worker threads waking up from sleep. Still seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: @knivil I tried MSVC and don't seem to be getting the problem but it's hard to know. The problem only occurs roughly once every 1000 frames or so (in MinGW, tried for a couple of minutes in MSVC and didn't get any freeze). In general I find it difficult to test threaded code.

Comment: And now I've had it running for 30 minutes so it definitely seems to be working on MSVC...

Comment: Ok, after setting some breakpoints I found that the second lock (for decreasing mUnfinishedJobs) is never used so of course the compiler optimizes it out (duh). This can certainly be a problem but I'm not sure why it would freeze in AddJob, surely it'd freeze in Wait if I'm getting stale reads (because it's waiting for mFinishedJobs to get to 0 but that never happened). Anyhow, I'll do what Sergey suggested and use a single lock that I lock/unlock instead of using constructor/destructor and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Chainsawkitten: You did not test threaded code, you design it correctly upfront. Tools for that are e.g. petri nets, experience or using libraries.

Comment: Lock and unlocking the lock manually rather than using the constructor/destructor didn't solve it. (I suspected as much since that'd freeze in Wait, not Add.)

Comment: @Chainsawkitten I suggest reducing and reducing to a MVCE and then posting the assembler! I've desk checked this and re-read the documentation and can't see the flaw. How much of `Execute` can you comment out before it starts working? PS: You can use `std::lock_guard` in a couple of places. That is more efficient but shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I did what you suggested (as well as manually locking the `unique_lock`) and now it's been running for 20 minutes without freezing (though that's not a guarantee...). I got the idea from elsewhere (can't remember where) that notifying outside the lock was fine (and in fact preferable due to performance reasons) but perhaps I got the wrong idea. What exactly about a `condition_variable` could cause an issue if you notify outside the lock?

Comment: notify_one() and notify_all() do not synchronize. Only lock/unlock mutex operation synchronize with other threads.

Comment: @Chainsawkitten Sorry, my bad. I've misread the code with these brackets here and there.